# How to restart apache using nant script

Tags: xml, apache, release, nant

I need to restart my apache using nant script. How can I do that?

I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
<exec program="php.exe" basedir="${phpexedir}" commandline="${userGuest}@${dbHost} -pw ${pwGuest}  " service httpd start " "/>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Probably, it's all about syntax part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="some-service">
    <target name="apache-restart">
        <property name="apache-bin" value="C:\Program Files\apache2\bin"/>
        <exec program ="httpd.exe" basedir="${apache-bin}">
            <arg value="-k"/>
            <arg value="restart"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

You can save this nant-project to file and then run it with "nant.exe /f:your-file.build apache-restart"

:-D